# Need a method to protectively replace user's input based on token criteria

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an input (i.e. textbox) that allows users to enter in tokens.

```
> Hello {{firstname}} {{lastname}}!
```

These tokens are replaced with user data once it hits the server. I'd like to implement some protective methods that "fixes" the input before it's submitted.

So for example, the following should be fixed/changed to `{{firstname}}`

- {{First Name}}
- {FirstName}
- {{FirstName}}
- {{FirstName}}
- {{first name}}
- {{ first name}}
- Other variations...

I'm attempting something like this, but surely it's not optimal and is prone to issues:

```
var properFirstName = "{{firstname}}";
var replaceValues = {
    "firstname": properFirstName,
    "{{first name}}": properFirstName,
    "{firstname}": properFirstName
};

for (var txt in replaceValues) {
    var rx = new RegExp(txt, "ig");
    this.formData.message = this.formData.message.replace(rx, replaceValues[txt]);
}
```

My example above fails, and purposely so to point out some issues (Value ends up with many brackets around it {{{{firstname}}}} and more on each blur event). So this token along with several others I'd need a smarter way to evaluate things like:

- Anything resembling the "firstname" token lacking proper brackets on both sides?
- Anything resembling the "firstname" token have spaces or other issues?

Capitalization is no big deal, and I can even change the server side method to ignore case, but the rest I'd like to resolve on the client prior to submission.

To add to this, perhaps I need to dial back the protective measures on things like "firstname" ... never know when someone will want to purposely enter that for whatever strange reason. Maybe the search/correcting always looks for at least one curly bracket to exist around the value? I don't want my protective programming to actually be a stumbling block.

Comment: What are *other issues*? Whitespace can be handled with `\s*` in between the chars, but as for other issues, you should come up with some requirements.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I updated my question. Basically it ends up stacking the brackets `{{{{...}}}}` more and more on each blur. So trying to fix `{firstname}` or `firstname` will continually end up with more and more curly braces around it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew My requirements are also part of my question. The general idea is to find the best way to detect a matching part of the string that resembles an attempt of the user to enter in a token.

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/3jwbc8cp/

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Looks genius to me. Testing the fire out of it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can't find issues. Clean, smart, and efficient. Please post this as an answer so I can give proper credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following solution:

```js
var properFirstName = "{{firstname}}";
var replaceValues = /{*\s*first\s*name\s*}*/i;
var message = "{ \nfirst\tName}}";
message = message.replace(replaceValues, "{{firstname}}");
console.log(message);
```

The pattern is `/{*\s*first\s*name\s*}*/i`, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lwrNMy/1).

**Details**

- `{*`  - 0+ `{`s
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `first` - a literal substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `name` - a literal substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `}*` - 0+ `}`s.

Comment: You're awesome. I wrapped this to iterate over all my replace types. Thank you so much.